# Azure Logic App CosmosDB Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic App that replaces a CosmosDB document. The DocumentID to be replaced in this example run is set to `"JTJmbWVkaWEtc3RvcmUlMmZzdXBlcl9tYXJpb19icm9zX3RyYWlsZXIubXA0"` (URL Param). When I set the DocumentID in Replace a Document (V2) it is throwing a `Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system.` error even though the "id" matches the DocumentID.

[image: Logic App Error Message]

I have /id as the partition key. Anyone any ideas?

[image: CosmosDB Item Existing]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which is the Partition Key Definition of the container? Are you passing the Partition Key value for that document?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta The Partition Key is '/id' and each Document contains an 'id' key value. Not sure if that answers your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first screenshot does not show you are passing the Partition Key. When we look at the Logic Apps docs for "Get a Document (V2)": https://learn.microsoft.com/connectors/documentdb/#get-a-document-(v2)

It has the `Partition Key value` parameter:

[image: Screenshot of parameter Partition Key value]

When reading a document from Cosmos DB, both the `id` and Partition Key value are required, even if they are the same value (in your case `/id` is the Partition Key Definition).

Try adding the parameter with the same value as `Document ID`.

Comment: Hi, even when I pass DocumentID  as `JTJmbWVkaWEtc3RvcmUlMmZwb2tlbW9uLXNjYXJsZXQtdmlvbGV0LXRyYWlsZXIubXA0` and Partition Key Value as `"JTJmbWVkaWEtc3RvcmUlMmZwb2tlbW9uLXNjYXJsZXQtdmlvbGV0LXRyYWlsZXIubXA0"`

I now get a different error:
`Message: {\"Errors\":[\"Resource Not Found.`

Comment: Got it working now, made a new cosmosDb in case it was the issue with Partition Key being /id and forgot to change it over after passing the Partition Key.

Passing the Partition Key in enclosed "" solved the issue!